# multidimensional (2D) function plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm looking into plotting functions and I've run into `persp` and `curve` but I'm not able to follow them to plot a 2D function.

They are for *surface plots*, yes?

If I had a function like `x^2 + y^2` `[x,y] in [-3,3]` how do I go about it?
Any links will be much appreciated and critique on existing packages (if multiple) ? gold.

Thanks.

Comment: see `?curve3d` in the `emdbook` package, for example.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To use `persp`, you need to supply values of `x`, values of `y`, and values of `z` for each combination of `x` and `y`. The easiest way to do this is to define `x` and `y` and then use `outer` to create a matrix that crosses `x` and `y`. You need to specify the way the two variables should be combined as the third argument to `outer`, in this case the function `+`:

```
x <- seq(-3,3,length.out=100)
y <- seq(-3,3,length.out=100)
z <- outer(x^2,y^2,`+`)
persp(x,y,z, col='blue')
```

[image]

You may also be interested in rotating the results. Here are some examples using the `theta` parameter:

```
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
layout(matrix(1:4, nrow=2))
s=lapply(c(0,30,60,90), function(t) persp(x,y,z, col='blue', theta=t))
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I understand from your comment you would like a 2D representation of this surface. The easiest way to get that in base R is with `image` of your `z` matrix:

```
image(z)
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, thanks for it.

However, I am looking for a 2-D plot, not a perspective plot. 

If I were to plot a circle, using x^2 + y^2 for example.